# Porting C++ application (no interface, only algorithm) to Android?

Tags: java, android, c++

**Hello!**

I learn computer sciences and i'm in internship for 2 months. I have to port a C++ application using the Standard Template Library to Android.
The application hasn't interface, it's only algorithms in C++ (very object-oriented). There are multiples of headers and cpp files with a main.cpp file and a folder where are stored ressources needed for calculating (it's about GPS informations).
I made many searches and some solutions came:
- Translate all the code in Java with tools like "C++ to Java Converter", it may be not really efficient, i'm not sure about this.
- Create a C++ compiled library and add it to the Android Studio project: seems to be a good plan but I have no idea how to do it. They're talking about SWIG which uses JNI or about Android Native Development Toolkit but i read that it was efficient only if that was used to developp little parts of the Android app.

I hope you can help because I've very little time to do it and this is the first part of my subject...

Comment: I'd start from the [official Android NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides).

Comment: In order to help you better, you will have to be a bit more precise about the code you were given. What is the shape of its input and what are its outputs? If it just uses basic numbers and arrays you can get by with basic JNI operations. If it needs complex data structures, you will either need custom Java code to build those data structures (that pushes into C++), JNI code that pulls from Java or simply  formulate your input as YAML/JSON and pass that as a byte buffer.

Answer (score 1):

There may be no need for translating it...

> You can add C and C++ code to your Android project by placing the code into a cpp directory in your project module. When you build your project, this code is compiled into a native library that Gradle can package with your APK. Your Java or Kotlin code can then call functions in your native library through the Java Native Interface (JNI). To learn more about using the JNI framework, read JNI tips for Android.

You can find further information behind this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code)